# Electron pairing in atoms

Tags: molecular-orbital-theory, electrons, electronic-configuration, atomic-structure

A question asks:

> This question refers to isolated gaseous atoms. In which atom are all electrons paired? Ba, Br, S or Si?

I thought it was Ba as its electron configuration is [Xe] 6s2.

However, the answer says Si, which seems incorrect to me.

Could someone please confirm the answer for me?

Thanks

Comment: Si seems incorrect to me as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The configuration for the free atoms is:

- Ba - $\mathrm{[Xe]\ 6s^2}$
- Br - $\mathrm{[Ar]\ 3d^{10} 4s^2 4p^5}$
- S - $\mathrm{[Ne]\ 3s^2 3p^4}$
- Si - $\mathrm{[Ne]\ 3s^2 3p^2}$

Thus:

- Barium has no unpaired electrons.
- Bromine has one unpaired electron in 4p subshell.
- Sulfur has two unpaired electrons in the 3p subshell.
- Silicon has two unpaired electrons in the 3p subshell.